# why this JAVA codes(DoublyLinkedList) are error, stackOverflow

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

I don't know why it's stack overflow

Error message is this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at linkedList.Node.toString(DoublyLinkedList.java:15)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
```

and then same messages over and over again

this is first time i got this error, so please let me know why is this error occur.

this is for making doubly linked list.

when i commented //tail.next = newOne; or //newOne.prev = tail;

it works

thank you.

```
class Node{
    String val;
    Node next;
    Node prev;

    public Node(String val){
        this.val = val;
        this.next = null;
        this.prev = null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Node [val=" + val + ", next=" + next + ", prev=" + prev + "]";
    }

}

public class DoublyLinkedList {
    Node head;
    Node tail;
    int length;
    LinkedList<Integer> aa = new LinkedList<>();


    public DoublyLinkedList() {
        this.head = null;
        this.tail = null;
        this.length = 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DoublyLinkedList dd = new DoublyLinkedList();
        dd.push("asdad");
        dd.push("wwwwwww");
        System.out.println(dd.toString());
    }

    public void push(String val) {
        Node newOne = new Node(val);
        if(length == 0) {
            head = newOne;
            tail = newOne;
        } else {
            tail.next = newOne;
            newOne.prev = tail;
            tail = newOne;
        }

        length++;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DoublyLinkedList [head=" + head + ", tail=" + tail + ", length=" + length + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you left some code out.

Comment: In your Node, there is a Node, in that Node, there is a Node, in that Node, there is a Node, ...

Comment: When you include `next` in the string returned by `toString()`, it really means `next.toString()`. Same for `prev.toString()`. So when `node.toString()` is called, it calls `next.toString()` aka `node.next.toString()`, and it calls `prev.toString()` aka `node.next.prev.toString()`, which calls `next.toString()` aka `node.next.prev.next.toString()`, which calls `prev.toString()` aka `node.next.prev.next.prev.toString()`, which ..., STACK OVERFLOW!!! --- You really don't want `node.toString()` to print all other nodes in the list, so remove `next` and `prev` from that `toString()` implementation

Comment: maybe just print the values of the next/previous nodes (if present), despite this is only helpful for debugging, *normal* display/output would look a bit strange with that information

Comment: oh! now i can see what cause the stackoverflow! Thanks guys really!